# gvfs is not mounting my Google Pixel

Tags: gvfs

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 on a Macbook.  I'm running Gnome.  GVFS does not seem to be mounting my Pixel phone anymore.  Per syslog, USB seems to be seeing the phone and identifying it properly, but it doesn't show up in nautilus or under /rn/user/UID/gvfs.

ls -l /usr/run/UID/gvfs

dr-x------ 2 hughc users   0 Jul 12 17:58 gvfs

That's not how that's supposed to look, is it?  Why wouldn't it be writable to me?

Comment: Are you able to pull files with ADB?